Broken Pipe error with uses threads to receive messages in the background while using input()
I am creating a python chat app and with my client, I want to be able to send input() to the server while also getting messages from the server, basically receiving messages while ALSO being able to send input(), i've "achieved" this by using a thread to receive messages, but I end up with a broken pipe error as soon as the client uses '!quit', which is the command to quit.
Here is the client code i've made:
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time

class Client:
    # data buffer size
    DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        # create client socket then connect to server
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.connect((host, port))
        # receive messages thread
        # daemon is true so it runs in the background
        self.receive_messages = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_messages, daemon=True)
        self.receive_messages.start()

    def close(self, send_message=True):
        if send_message:
            # send !quit to the server so it knows we are quitting the program
            self.client.send('!quit'.encode())
            # wait for the server to send us 'ack' so then we know that the server knows we are about to quit
            # receive function waits for a message from the server, so it wont continue executing code, it will wait for data to be received
            print(self.client.recv(Client.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE))
        # finally, quit
        print('closing client')
        self.client.close()
        # exit program with error code 0, meaning no error
        sys.exit(0)

    # receive messages function for receive messages thread
    # this lets the client receive new messages while also allowing the user to send messages
    def receive_messages(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.client.send('ack'.encode())
            msg = self.client.recv(Client.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE)
            if msg and msg.decode() == '!ack':
                break

    # loop function
    def loop(self):
        try:
            while True:
                msg = input('message -> ')
                # send input to the server
                self.client.send(msg.encode())
                # receive message from server
                print(self.client.recv(Client.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE))
                if msg == '!quit':
                    # we've sent '!quit' already, so set send_message to false
                    self.close(send_message=False)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.close()

def main():
    # create client and loop
    client = Client('172.31.196.42', 7777)
    client.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This might not help but here is the server code if needed:
import threading
import socket
import sys

class Server:
  # buffer size for data that should be sent around
  DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
  
  # connection class to make it easier handling multiple clients
  class Connection:
    def __init__(self, server):
      self.conn, self.addr = server.accept()
      print(f'accepted new connection from {self.addr}')
      self.user = 'Anonymous'

    def close(self):
      print(f'closing connection to user {self.user}, addr: {self.addr}')
      # close connection
      self.conn.close()
  
  def __init__(self, port):
    # get ip of host computer
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    # create server socket
    self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server.bind((host, port))
    self.server.listen()
    print(f'server binded to {host}:{port}')
    self.running = True
    # clients
    self.clients = []
    # accept connections thread
    # this thread will run in the background so the server will accept new clients while also handling current clients
    # daemon means it will run in the background, so we will set daemon to True
    self.accept_connections = threading.Thread(target=self.accept_connections, daemon=True)
    self.accept_connections.start()

  # close function
  def close(self):
    print('closing server')
    # loop through all the client connections, then close them
    for client in self.clients:
      client.close()
    # close the main server
    self.server.close()

  def close_client(self, client_id):
    # first close the connection
    self.clients[client_id].close()
    # then pop the client of the list
    self.clients.pop(client_id)

  # function that accepts connections in the background
  def accept_connections(self):
    while True:
      self.clients.append(Server.Connection(self.server))

  # broadcast function - sends a message to all clients
  def broadcast(self, msg):
    for client in self.clients:
      # we must receive data before sending data
      client.conn.recv(Server.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE)
      client.conn.send(msg)

  def loop(self):
    # try except statement to catch when the server host presses CTRL+C, then close the server
    try:
      while True:
        for client in self.clients:
          # recieve message from client
          msg = client.conn.recv(Server.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
          print(f'received message from {client.user}: {msg}')
          client.conn.send('ack'.encode())
          if msg == '!quit':
            # the message is !quit, meaning we will now destroy the client out of the giant list of clients
            # close the client
            # self.clients.index(client) finds the id or index of the actual client
            self.close_client(self.clients.index(client))
          else:
            # broadcast the message to all clients
            self.broadcast(f'{client.user}: {msg}'.encode())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      # close server
      self.close()
      # exit program with code 0 meaning the program is fine
      sys.exit(0)

def main():
  # start server on port 7777 and loop
  server = Server(7777)
  server.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()


You have not "achieved" this by using a thread to receive messages, since you're using one and the same thread also for input().

I fixed it, I literally just switched the entire thing to udp, easy peasy.

The Broken Pipe error typically occurs when one side of a network connection tries to write to it while the other side has already closed the connection. This is likely happening in your case when the client sends the !quit command to the server, and then either the server or client closes the connection before all the pending messages are properly handled or acknowledged.
I changed the receive message code as below:
def receive_messages(self):
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.client.send('ack'.encode())
            msg = self.client.recv(Client.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE)
            if msg and msg.decode() == '!ack':
                break
        except OSError:
            break #Handling the case if client socket is closed


how do I make the fix the code so if client2 sends a message client1 gets that message as well as the server even if client1 is still typing, I'm just really confused, its not really working the way I want it to.
